# How to get the variable that caused a ReferenceError to be thrown in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

This can be done by getting the actual variable name, or the detailed error message (like the one printed in the browser's console)

```
try {
    alert(v); // v is undefined so a ReferenceError will be thrown
}
catch(err) {
    alert(err.getVariableName()); // should return "v"
}
```

Update 1: I want this error to be handled from an external JS file, so I tried the following:

```
<script>window.onerror = function(e){ console.log("caught error: "+e.message); return true;}</script>
<script src="faulty.js"></script>
```

But it returns undefined for e.message, although e.message works normally when used inside a try-catch statement as explained in @Badacadabra's answer

Comment: Try `err.toString()` to get the message that would have been printed in the console

Comment: If you're doing this for debugging purposes, you could set a breakpoint and step through your code to see where you're hitting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the name, you can use `String.prototype.split()` on `err.message`:

```js
try {
  alert(v);
} catch (err) {
  alert(err.message.split(' ')[0]);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

`window.onerror` handler has a specific signature. Its first parameter is the error message and its last parameter is the `Error` object. In your case, you could do this:

```js
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, err) {
  console.log(err.message.split(' ')[0]);
}

alert(v);
```

Or just this:

```js
window.onerror = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg.split(' ')[1]);
}

alert(v);
```

Comment: It works for inline scripts, however, when tried with external scripts, `err` is `null`, and `msg` is `Script error`. Is it possible to use it with external scripts?

Comment: That moment when you realize your code works in IE... xD I think your question is becoming a bit too broad. I suggest you to read this: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Think you might have to regex from a default error like
regex from err.message or err.stack

looks at @ badacadra solution, smacks my head lol, his solution is good

Comment: Badacadabra LOL THAT Solution works, nice intuitive solution!`

Comment: Yes, the variable name is the first word in `err.message`. `err.name` would return the name of the error (`ReferenceError`). :)